# Garage Door Won't Start

Tags: garage-door

My garage door won't open. I've tried to push up on it when starting assuming something needs lube, I've checked all the cables and oiled everything, the floor-mounted trip sensors are fine. When I press the button, there is a a short start represented by a clicking sound. If I keep pressing, the door will go down and then back up eventually.

The video below is probably the most clear description of the problem.

https://youtu.be/t7izeDAhVvc

Thank you for any troubleshooting ideas. I've been manually raising the door for 6 months.

Comment: Since you can manually open it, presumably the mechanical lube/adjusting of the door mechanism is fine, unless that's very hard to do.

Answer (score 3):

If "the sensors are good" and you have attempted to follow the adjusting/troubleshooting steps for your opener (see the web if you can't find your paper manual) then it's *probably* a fried logic board. Garage door openers are basically tiny computers.

A new opener comes with a warranty, a new logic board does not, so the choice is not all that straightforward - it **could** be something else in the opener, and a non-returnable non-warranty logic board is often half the price of a whole new opener, with a warranty. So unless you have *excellent* reason to think it's the logic board (I had a fairly new opener and a nearby lighting strike; & it was *still* a dice roll) whole-system replacement is the more certain path to success.

Comment: It could be the spring failed and the motor stalls.

Comment: If it was a failed spring he wouldn't be able to open it manually which is what he has been doing the last 6 months.

Comment: Well. I’m pretty sure a failed logic board wouldn’t start. My guess is that something is getting stuck on start. But at this point it’s just easier to get a new one