# Dead garage door opener

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a ten year old Craftsman, three quarter horse, chain drive opener.  It is totally dead. No lights, motor, nothing. Power outlet is good. Chain is properly tight. I plug it back into the outlet and it works properly for about two days with multiple opens and closes. Then again it goes dead. Once in a while it will stop about one foot into closing but will continue to close with a second tap on the button. Does this with either older light bulbs or new LED. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It is dying and you will need to replace it.

Comment: Used to be ten year old is just getting broken in, not dying.  No wonder I get scared thinking about replacing my 80s/90s appliances with new ones.

Comment: open it up and check the cable connections, you might have loose contact

Comment: What happens when you disconnect it from the opener and operate by hand? Easy/smooth or hard and heavy? Have you gone through all the calibration checks? But likely, if it's becoming totally unresponsive; replacement. See also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/249182/18078

Comment: when it dies, is that happening while it's opening/closing, or just sitting there? If unplugging and re-plugging fixes it, for now put it on an appliance timer when all the slots are on except on at 3AM-3:15AM or whatever. Might work for years to come...